# Convert `uchar*` to `uchar4*` in Metal

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

Currently, I'm dealing with 2 types of data in my kernel function: RGBA color as `uchar4*` and indexed color as `uchar*`. It would be great if I could quickly convert the `uchar*` into `uchar4*`, so that I only need to pass in only 1 buffer for both cases and if it's RGBA data, I can just convert the `uchar*` to `uchar4*` to use the convenient accessors.

Is there any performant way of doing that?

Comment: You cannot do that in general. `uchar4` needs 4 bytes of alignment, while `uchar` only needs 1. So you can't just go from any random `uchar*` to a `uchar4*`.

Comment: If you know they are aligned for sure, you can just cast them like any other pointer, I don't see why this is a performance question.

Comment: oh, so I can just do `(uchar4*) array`? and yes, I know that they will align correctly. I do not have much knowledge of C. Thank you, let me try that